# Offline mode in ionic-angular 2 app

Tags: sqlite, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, couchdb

**How can we convert our online app into offline app in ionic 2 ?**

when we are **fetching** all the data from the server using api's and api's are sending us the **url's** of the **images** and other sort of data.

If these are the solutions :

**1- couchdb + pouchdb**

**2- sqlite**

**then which one of them is the best to implement it in our ionic-angular 2 app or there is some other solution**.

Answer (score 0):

Is the data on the server already stored in a ChouchDB and do you want to keep the data synchronized? In that case, I would definitely go for CouchDB + PouchDB on the client side. Local data can easily be replicated with the server and vice versa, see [PouchDB's documentation](https://pouchdb.com/guides/replication.html).

Besides this approach, there are several other solutions such as Firebase, Couchbase, Cloudant and some more.

Comment: I am only using api's to fetch data from the server. I don't know where the data is stored.

Comment: I only want to synchronize data when the user enable the internet on his/her device 

@Onno

Comment: In that case you do not need a combination of CouchDB/PouchDB. If you just want to store data fetched by API calls, you can choose any storage engine you want. I would go for the [storage service](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/) provided by Ionic, which  automatically picks the best storage engine available depending on the platform.

Comment: @ShehramTahir Accepting the answer will be great. :)